# Get attribute from body tag. Selenium Webdriver

Tags: html, dom, web, selenium-webdriver

I have body tag with attributes from which I need to get email address to assert in Selenium WebDriver test. Is it able to go it via default locators?

```
<body ng-init=" user={"id":43,"email":"EMAIL@gmail.com","username":"USER_NAME","balance":2259,"location":null,"d
escription":null,"fullname":"FULL_NAME","notification_settings":
{"newsletter":true,"follower":true,"mention":true,"comment":true},"settings":{"nsfw":false}};
user.small_avatar_url ='http://cdn.stage.uprise.com/user/43/small_34_34_20131111162316735';
" ng-class="(notice) ? 'with-notice' : ''" data-twttr-rendered="true" class="">
```

Solution what is workig for me is here:

```
    String nginit =  this.getBrowser().findElement(By.tagName("body")).getAttribute("ng-init");
    String[] arr = nginit.split(",");
    for ( String ss : arr) {
        if(ss.contains("email")) {
            String[] email = ss.split("\"");
            this.loggedinEmail = email[3];
        }
    }
```

Comment: What language bindings (eg C#/ Java) are you using? What have you tried?

Comment: I suppose ng-init is the major attribute containing most of the information. then u can use Driver.FindElement(By.ByTagName("Body")).getAttribute("ng-init");
Later u have to parse the string to fetch the Email for assertion

Comment: I using java. I email by running javascript getAttribute method, and than i iterate through whole string. So i've done the same but with javascript code.

Comment: @brbrr: Did u try the same with Selenium as i mentioned in my comment?

Comment: @Anuragh27crony Yeah, just tried. Works good. Thanks!

Comment: @brbrr : Then i will submit this as answer, please accept it :) So that it will be useful for others visiting the forum for solutions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since email is part value of attribute "***ng-init***" of "***body***" tag. I would recommend to fectch the element with the help of Body tag and then retrieve "ng-init" element.

Later you can parse the string, to verify/utilize the E-mail.

```
String Input= Driver.FindElement(By.ByTagName("Body")).getAttribute("ng-init");
```

then parse it with string tokenizer as follows

```
StringTokenizer tokens=new StringTokenizer(Input,",");
String temp=null;
String Email=null;

    while(tokens.hasMoreTokens()){
            temp=tokens.nextToken();
        if(temp.contains("email")){
            Email=temp.split("\"")[3];
            System.out.println(Email);
            break;
        }
```

Answer (score -2):

I'am not sure try this..

```
option=driver.find_element_by_class_name("")
email=option.get_attribute("email")
```